# Using Dygraphs to dynamically load dense data based on range

Tags: javascript, dynamic-data, dygraphs

I have a scenario which involves a lot of data and I would like to load most of it dynamically.

In the ideal scenario when the the user loads the webpage with Dygraphs instance on it only the data in some predefined range is loaded. At the same time the range selector below displays the "shape" of the whole data.

Furthermore, when the user selects a different range the data for that range is loaded (lets disregard the issue of overlapping ranges for the simplicity and assume everything in the new range will be loaded).

How can I achieve this form of dynamic data loading while at the same time have the whole range available for the range selector.

Answer (score 5):

One user created some [demos](http://kaliatech.github.io/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example/) that do something like this. There was a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/kgdNdt1A0dk) about it on the dygraphs mailing list.

The approach is described in more detail on the demo page, but the general idea is to load and render a coarse version of the data on page load, then augment it with finer-grained data as needed.

Another approach would be to create two charts with different data sources, one for the range selector and one for the zoomed-in chart. See the bottom chart on [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html).